# RxJS: How to delay next emitted value?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have async function `handleParamsChanges` which can take a few seconds to resolve. And I'm calling it when observable emits value:

```
this._activatedRoute.params
  .subscribe(params => {
    this.handleParamsChanges(params).then(() => {
      // new value can be processed now
    });
  });
```

How could I modify my code so that if observable emits 2 values one after another, first `handleParamsChanges` is called for first value, and only **after** this promise resolves, it's called with second value, and so on.

Edit:

Here is the solution I came up with, but I'm guessing there is a better way to do this:

```
const params$ = this._activatedRoute.params;
const canExecute$ = new BehaviorSubject(true);

combineLatest(params$, canExecute$)
  .pipe(
    filter(([_, canExecute]) => canExecute),
    map(([params]) => params),
    distinctUntilChanged()
  )
  .subscribe(async params => {
    canExecute$.next(false);
    try {
      await this.handleParamsChanges(params);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    } finally {
      canExecute$.next(true);
    }
  })
```

I'm using `canExecute$` to delay processing of new value.

I need to use `distinctUntilChanged` here to avoid creating infinite loop.

Comment: Why do you need to wait for `handleParamsChanges` to finish before the next value is processed?

Comment: I'm fetching data inside that function and updating my view. Without waiting, if two values are emitted one after another, it's possible that http request I'm making for second value completes before the first one, and that way I'm displaying wrong data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is `concatMap`. It waits for the previous "inner observable" to complete before subscribing again. Also you can greatly simplify your pipe:

```
params$.pipe(
  concatMap(params => this.handleParamsChanges(params)),
).subscribe()
```

Comment: I think switchMap might be a better fit? The idea is that stale values are thrown away, so it makes sense to cancel in-flight requests and get the fresh value asap (without waiting)

Comment: Nevermind. HandleParamChnages is a promise, so it can't be cancelled.